# Multimaps in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, multimap

I am trying to use multimaps in C++. The main aim is that there is a map that stores the multimap pointer.

Now when I try to insert into the multimap I am getting the problem. Can someone tell me where am I going wrong.

```
typedef multimap<int,int> mm;
typedef map<int,mm*> v_map;

int main()
{
v_map map1;

v_map::iterator it;
it = map1.find(23);

mm *mm_map_pointer;

if( it == map1.end())
  {
   mm m_map1; 
   map1[23] = &m_map1;
   mm_map_pointer = &m_map1;
  }
else
 {
   mm_map_pointer = it->second; 
 }

mm_map_pointer->insert( pair<int, int>(1, 2));
return 0;
}
```

The problem is with mm_map_pointer->insert( pair(1, 2));
Can someone help?

Comment: what is the problem? compiler error? runtime error?

Comment: "Can someone help?" If that's your question, then the answer is NO, because you haven't told us what the problem you want to solve is. What error are you getting? What happens when you try it? What did you expect would happen?

Comment: compiler error, in mm_map_pointer->insert( pair(1, 2));

Comment: What problem are you getting? The code compiles and runs OK (with the addition of `#include <map>; using namespace std;`).

Comment: Hi Jalf.. The problem is inserting in Multimap in a dynamic way. I want to have all this inside a loop so that I can create a new multimap whenever required.

Comment: @unapersson - good point, a dangling pointer shouldn't be a compiler error, though some compilers may spot this case through static analysis and give a warning. Should be a run-time error.

Comment: @Steve I didn't actually read the code, just compiled and ran it. Obviously, we are in a UB situation as regards running it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `m_map1` is a local variable, and you're trying to store a pointer to that in your `map`. This results in a *dangling pointer* when the block containing that variable exits.

You have two ways to solve this:

- My preferred way is to store the `multimap` in the `map` directly (i.e., not using a pointer). As a bonus, this simplifies your code a *lot*:

  ```
  typedef multimap<int, int> mm;
  typedef map<int, mm> v_map;

  v_map map1;
  map1[23].insert(make_pair(1, 2));
  ```

  That's it!
- Your other option is to use `new` to create a persistent copy of the `multimap`. In this case, your `map` should hold a `shared_ptr<multimap<...> >` so that you don't have to deallocate the `multimap` manually.

Answer (score 5):

```
{
 mm m_map1; 
 map1[23] = &m_map1;
 mm_map_pointer = &m_map1;
} // end of scope
```

Your problem is that `m_map1` goes out of scope and is destroyed, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

Comment: Thanks Ben, can you suggest me something, how to have dynamic multimap ie create the multimap inside the loop and initialize it anywhere.

Comment: @user328560: Simple! Just take out the star in the `v_map` typedef. ;-) (That's the "store the `multimap` directly" approach as mentioned in my answer. As a bonus, it also makes your code about a fifth of its original size.)